# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python

I have this piece of code to create a .json file to store python data. When i run it in my server i get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'juliodantas2015.json' at line with open(output_file, 'wb') as fp:
```

**Python code:**

```
fich_input='juliodantas2015.txt'
output_file= fich_input.strip('.txt')+'.json'
import json
with open(output_file, 'wb') as fp:
    json.dump('yes', fp)
```

In command line i typed **chmod 777 *.py** but still not working. How can i fix this ?

Comment: It's not the .py file it is complaining about, it is your json file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'juliodantas2015.json'
```

tells you everything you need to know: though you successfully made your python program executable with your `chmod`, python can't open that `juliodantas2015.json'` file for writing. You probably don't have the rights to create new files in the folder you're currently in.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand. Made chmod 777 in that folder and now it is working.

Comment: that's a bit dangerous, because now *everyone* can do *whatever* they want to that folder. I recommend reading chmod's man page, and a bit on unix file permissions!

Comment: How would you define permissions in this case?

Comment: Done chmod +w  to avoid 777

Comment: @JoãoPedro and Marcus how did you do this without setting chmod to 777?

Comment: @spenf10 specify "this"?

Comment: @spenf10 assuming the user executing the python program is the same as the owner of the JSON file, the only user having to have access is the owner, i.e. a 600 would totally suffice.

Comment: saved my life :) @MarcusMüller

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem. I was attempting to have a file written every time a user visits a website.

The problem ended up being twofold.

1: the permissions were not set correctly

2: I attempted to use 
`f = open(r"newfile.txt","w+")` (Wrong)

After changing the file to 777 (all users can read/write)
`chmod 777 /var/www/path/to/file`
and changing the path to an absolute path, my problem was solved 
`f = open(r"/var/www/path/to/file/newfile.txt","w+")` (Right)

Answer (score 0):

I have a really stupid use case for why I got this error.  Originally I was printing my data > file.txt

Then I changed my mind, and decided to use open("file.txt", "w") instead.  But when I called python, I left > file.txt .....

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue this morning when I tried to write data to opened excel file note that you can not edit a file when it's open .
Please close the file and then  it work  normally

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31916655)