# with open(file_name, 'w') as my_file: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python

I create a file and store some text in it. On WSL it works, but on my server it doesnt work?
It this a user permission issue on the server or is there something wrong in the code.

```
file_name = str(self.pk) + 'host.ics'
    with open(file_name, 'w') as my_file:
        my_file.writelines(c)
```

Its created on my WSL but on the linux server it gives this error:

```
in send_email_client with open(file_name, 'w') as my_file: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '12host.ics'
```

Comment: Is the file open on your computer before executing the code? That is the first thing I check when I get that error.

Comment: Yes, I remember got this error while doing a file operation.I do run it with "sudo !!".Try it.

Comment: did you check the permission set on this file? ```ls -la .```. You might need to add a read permission

Comment: How do I do it with sudo then? This code is run in models in Django

Comment: @DavidErickson no, the file does not exist before I create it in the code

Comment: If you are getting permission denied when trying to create a new file, then you do not have write permission on the directory. Rather than rush to using sudo to gain elevated privileges, instead consider whether the permissions on the directory could be changed so that it is writable by the user which is running the script (or a group which that user is a member of). In most cases, that will be the appropriate solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331872/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1):

I moved the file to the /tmp folder instead. Since the file I needed to create only exist for a few seconds.

```
file_name = '/tmp/' + str(self.pk) + 'host.ics'
    with open(file_name, 'w') as my_file:
        my_file.writelines(c)
```

Comment: BTW, if this is actually a temporary file, you can use the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tempfile.html) library...